# Pandas: sum consecutive rows satisfying condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame of the form

| index | value | condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 11 | False |
| 1 | 12 | True |
| 2 | 13 | True |
| 3 | 14 | False |
| 4 | 15 | True |
| 5 | 16 | True |
| 6 | 17 | True |
| 7 | 18 | False |

My goal is to get all differences of the value of consecutive groups of rows satisfying the condition, i.e. in this example, I want to have a list `[13 - 12, 17 - 15]`. Is there an efficient way with pandas to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) on `condition` column to identify the `blocks` of rows satisfying the condition, then `group` the column `value` on these `blocks` and `agg` using [`numpy.ptp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html):

```
m = df['condition']
blocks = (~m).cumsum()[m]
lst = list(df['value'].groupby(blocks).agg(np.ptp))
```

**Details:**

```
>>> blocks

1    1
2    1
4    2
5    2
6    2
Name: condition, dtype: int64

>>> lst 

[1, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain a little bit in detail, why this works?

Comment: @mathology Edited the answer.